# case statement issue

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 2 columns have same name

```
ValueA  ValueB  ValueA
12      Yes     
        No      NULL
20      Yes    
0       No      0
3       No      3
```

Logic is that

- when `ValueA` is `''`
- and `ValueB` is `'No'`
- then `ValueA` in second column should be `''` (not `NULL`)

I wrote this case statement but it gives me `NULL` instead of `''`

```
Case when ValueB ='No' then convert(varchar(25), ValueA)
when ValueB ='No' and ValueA ='' then ''
else ''
end
```

even if I write

```
Case when ValueB
when 'No' then convert(varchar(25), ValueA) 
else ''
end
```

both of above code gives me same results

How can I replace or remove `NULL` with `''` in second ValueA column?

Comment: I truely doubt you have 2 columns with the same name in the same table

Comment: It's a malformed description - The second instance of ValueA is actually the derived output the OP is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope i understand the question correct, you can use coalesce or isnull to replace null values.

This could be your case statement:

```
case when ValueB = 'Yes' then '' 
     when ValueB = 'No' then coalesce(cast(ValueA as varchar(25)), '') 
else null     end
```

Comment: only when valueB is No and ValueA is blank then second column ValueA should be blank and not NULL.I am displaying null and trying to change it into blank in second ValueA column

Comment: @user680865 this solution should do exactly that.

Comment: it changes ValueA values of null to 0 or zero. Should I use coalesce(convert(varchar(25),ValueA)) instead to make ValueA values blank rather than 0?

Comment: @user680865 yes, if ValueA is numeric

Answer (score 1):

You need a specific case where you specify `NULL` as the output.

```
CASE WHEN ValueA = '' AND ValueB = 'No' THEN NULL
     WHEN                 ValueB = 'No' THEN convert(varchar9250, ValueA)
                                        ELSE ''
END
```

**EDIT**

I mis-understood your question then.  But you can use the same approach...

```
CASE WHEN ValueA = '' AND ValueB = 'No' THEN ''
     WHEN                 ValueB = 'No' THEN convert(varchar9250, ValueA)
                                        ELSE ''
END
```

Or, as people have suggested, use ISNULL or COALESCE to remove the NULL values...

```
CASE WHEN ValueB = 'No' THEN ISNULL(convert(varchar9250, ValueA), '')
                        ELSE ''
END
```

Comment: then why not to use IsNULL function

Comment: I want to remove NULL so that is shows '' or blank value instead

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
Select
case when ValueA = '' and ValueB = 'No' then '' 
     when ValueB = 'No' then ValueA     else '' end  [ValueA]
from table
```